# Regex: Remove spaces in some punctuation

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings such as `abc pre - school unit` or `abc pre / school district` that I would need to delete additional spaces before and after hyphen and slash. These examples will become `abc pre-school unit` and `abc pre/school district`.

I attempted this solution, but this works just replacing either slash or hyphen with hyphen. How can I delete the spaces to get these strings?

`abc pre-school unit`
`abc pre/school district`

```
import re

text= ['abc pre - school unit', 'abc pre / school district']

for name in text:
    tmp= re.sub("\s+[-/]\s+" , "-", name)

    print(tmp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture the symbol and then replace with that:

```
text = ['abc pre - school unit', 'abc pre / school district']

for name in text:
    tmp = re.sub("\s+([/-])\s+" , "\\1", name)
    print(tmp)
```

This prints:

```
abc pre-school unit
abc pre/school district
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need assign it back as well

```
text= ['abc pre - school unit', 'abc pre / school district']
tmp=[]
for name in text:
    tmp.append(re.sub("\s+([-/])\s+" , r'\1', name))

tmp
['abc pre-school unit', 'abc pre/school district']
```

Or

```
newlist=list(map(lambda x : re.sub("\s+([-/])\s+" , r'\1', x),text))
```

Comment: The `Or` part of your answer is identical to mine, and was added substantially after I posted.

Answer (score 1):

in re.sub, you can capture a pattern by putting it in braces. You can refer to it in the replacement by using positional arguments such as \1, \2, \3

So the solution would be:
for name in text:
    tmp.append(re.sub("\s+([-/])\s+" , "\1", name))